# HTTPS Callable Function that returns async function returning empty object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a HTTPS Callable function of with the following structure:

```
/**
 * Accepts a friend request from another user
 */
export const acceptFriendRequest = functions.https.onCall(
    (data : standardStructs.fromToStruct, context) => {

    standardChecks(data, context)

    if (!context.auth || context.auth.uid === data.to){
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'invalid-argument',
            'You cannot do this operation to yourself!');
    }

    return async () => {
        const fromSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(...).once('value');
        const toSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(...).once('value');
        const inboxSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(...).once('value');

        const updates = {} as any;
        const response = {} as any
        updates[`...`] = null;
        updates[`...`] = null;

        //If the desintation doesn't exist, then let's just erase this friend request
        if (!toSnapshot.exists()){
            response.status = standardHttpsData.returnStatuses.NOTO
        }else if (!inboxSnapshot.exists()){ 
            //This user is trying to accept a request that was never sent to them
            response.status = standardHttpsData.returnStatuses.INVALID
        }else{
            updates[`...`] = toSnapshot.val();
            updates[`...`] = fromSnapshot.val();
            response.status = standardHttpsData.returnStatuses.OK
        }

        await admin.database().ref().update(updates);
        return response

    };     
});
```

For some reason, this function returns an empty object. Additionally, it doesn't make any writes to the database, even though the necessary snapshots exists for it to do so. 
I'm not sure why, because I am indeed retuning a promise, just like the documentation says I should if I'm doing asynchronous commands.

Comment: Can you pls give more details on your `standardHttpsData` object and associated `returnStatuses`, as well as how you intend to use this response in your front end?

Comment: returnStatuses is actually just a map of strings. On the client side, the returned object will be used to inform the user what happened with the function if it didn't necessarily fail with an error.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You may try the proposed solution in my answer. It would work with your `returnStatuses` map, since the map value can be JSON encoded. **However**, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) recommends handling the error in a different way, using an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll give it a try right now. Just to provide another layer of clarification though - any errors that are severe enough to justify throwing a httpsError object are actually checked for in the  standardChecks(data, context) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning an `async` function within your Callable Cloud Function, you should declare the handler [function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.html#handler:-function) as `async`, as follows:

```
export const acceptFriendRequest = functions.https.onCall(
    async (data : standardStructs.fromToStruct, context) => {

    standardChecks(data, context)

    if (!context.auth || context.auth.uid === data.to){
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'invalid-argument',
            'You cannot do this operation to yourself!');
    }

    const fromSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(...).once('value');
    const toSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(...).once('value');
    const inboxSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(...).once('value');

    //...

    await admin.database().ref().update(updates);
    return response

});
```

---

You don't give details on what is the `standardHttpsData` object and associated `returnStatuses` (nor you give details on `standardChecks`), but you should note that you need to return, in your Cloud Function, some "data that can be JSON encoded", see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result).

---

**Update following your comment above:**

The solution proposed here will work with your `returnStatuses` map, since the map value can be JSON encoded. However, note that the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) recommends handling the error in a different way, using an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`.

Comment: I see someone dowloaded this answer :-) Maybe you can explain why? If you think it is not clear or not valuable, I'll be interested in knowing why.